# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required: NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nltk

I am working on NLTK:

```
data = urllib.parse.urlencode({"text": "I'm good "}).encode('ascii')
u = urllib.request.urlopen("http://text-processing.com/api/sentiment/",data)
the_page = u.read()
print (the_page)
```

## Returns

```
b'{"probability": {"neg": 0.22531846855219551, "neutral": 
0.084284385065714951, "pos": 0.77468153144780449}, "label": "pos"}'
```

Which is clearly bytes, I want to convert this bytes array into dictionary to access value of the key "label"

```
d = dict(toks.split(":") for toks in the_page.decode("ascii").split(",") if 
toks)   #Error referred here


for key,value in d.items():
    if key is 'label':
        print (value)
#Should return pos
```

The script throws error, "ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required
"

Comment: That looks like JSON. Perhaps try using the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `json` module to convert it to a regular Python dictionary:

```
import json
d = json.loads(the_page.decode("utf-8"))
print(d["label"])
```

Hope this helps.